# How to dynamically change variable in mixin function in sass?

Tags: css, sass

I have this mixin function in my sass file, from which I want to count every time it is used. For every time the counter needs to increment by 1, so the right value will change accordingly.

The issue is that I have a unsorted list with a unknown amount of elements. The list items can be of a certain type, and if they are, they need to be placed totally differently in the view. I want to align them to the top right corner of the site by adding a `position: absolute` and then a dynamic right value (so they don't overlap).

I don't know if my approach is correct, but my question is how do I dynamically change the $item-number variable and then reference this value later ?

```
$item-number: 1 !default;

@function times($value1, $value2) {
    @return $value1 * $value2;
}

@function plus($value1, $value2) {
    @return $value1 + $value2;
}

@mixin child($n) {
    $item-number: plus($n, 1);
    &:nth-child(#{$n}){
          right: times(50px, $n) !important;
    }
}

li {

    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
            position: absolute;
            top: -30px;
            right: 0;
            @include child($item-number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sass can't do what you're asking - it doesn't know anything about your HTML. There may be another way however. You said the items are "of a certain type" - do they have a unique class or selector we can use?

Comment: Yes pretend li is the class. Separation the type of list items are already implemented. What i need is a dynamic right value

Comment: Sorry, can you post some example HTML? It might help me answer the question.

Comment: HTML is just a bunch of li inside an ul tag. Everything else seems irrelevant to this issue

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand: your initial description implies that *only some* of the `li` items in the `ul` should be aligned in the top right. Those items need a unique class or attribute so we can target them and ignore the other ordinary `li` items.

Comment: They have a unique class yes.

Comment: How many times do you want the sass mixin to run though? You will need to explicitly state a number for it to loop over else it will only run once.

Comment: I don't think it's possible: I tried a few things with `nth-of-type` and `counter` but couldn't get it to work. However this [blog post](https://medium.com/@MateMarschalko/css-select-nth-element-with-class-a313d080e2bf) had similar problems, and offers a potential solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specifically loop over the mixin a certain number of times, else how does the sass know how many `nth-child` selectors to create?

I've removed your custom functions to make my example cleaner, but you can see that I have created a loop around the call to the mixin, which runs 9 times, passing the index to the function each time:

```
@mixin child($n) {
    &:nth-child(#{$n}){
        right: (50px * $n) !important;
    }
}

li {
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    right: 0;

    @for $i from 1 through 9 {
        @include child($i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how many items the list will have - since it comes from a cms system.  It doesn't seem possible with sass alone. - what will happen if the loop is bigger than the number of elements? Let's say i know that the list will be maximum 15 in length

Comment: Nothing will really happen, you just need to define a number of times for the loop to run which will in turn mean that a specific number of css classes will be available. Really you want to set the value to as low as possible so that you don't end up with unnecessary css. If you believe the list will be at max 15 items long, just set the loop to run 15 times, if you are uncertain, set it to 20, 25 etc.

Comment: Okay that might be a great solution, will update when i verify. Thanks!